# How to make Reflector an addin for Visual Studios?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, reflector

I downloaded [Reflector.Net](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) and it's an .Exe outside VS. I remember (last year) when I downloaded it, it was an Addin to VS. How can I make it back to an Addin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Reflector Add-In Lives Again ;-)](http://weblogs.asp.net/nunitaddin/archive/2006/08/01/ReflectorAddInLivesAgain.aspx)

P.S. The reflector add-in that made Reflector an Visual Studio add-in is discontinued.